# Automatically download file from URL

Tags: java, download

I am attempting to download a file automatically. I know the link as I have already parsed it from the RSS XML file. Is there a simple noob friendly way of doing this?

Since my previous edit I have been informed that as long as I keep the file name the same I will be able to do this this is the code I have so far (I should have mentioned previously that this is for a bukkit plugin however the plugin)

```
public void getFile (String url) {
    try{
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new

        URL("http://dev.bukkit.org/media/files/706/595/Kustom-Warn.jar").openStream());
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(plugin.getDataFolder().getAbsolutePath() + "/KustomWarn.jar");
        logger.severe(String.valueOf(plugin.getDataFolder().getAbsolutePath()));
        BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream,1024);
        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        while(in.read(data,0,1024)>=0)
        {
            outputStream.write(data);
        }
        outputStream.close();
        in.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        logger.severe("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be clear on what you are asking?

Comment: More detail please, what have you tried already?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean to copy a file from a site to a local file then you can use java.nio.file

```
Files.copy(new URL("http://host/site/filename").openStream(), Paths.get(localfile));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [URL.openStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) to open the stream and [Java NIO (New I/O)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_I/O) to read efficiently.